# Trying to run octave through Runtime.exec in a JSF application

Tags: java, linux, jsf, glassfish, octave

Ok, so my situation is as follows: I NEED to run a .mod file (a mathematical model) in Octave (a mathematical program used for advanced calculations), get its result and return for the user THROUGH a webapp.

Not that much really, I have a application that run as smoothly as one would need on my windows enviro (development enviro, I developed it using Glassfish 4.0 and Eclipse) with the following code:

```
...

        Process p = rt.exec("C:\\Octave\\Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2\\bin\\octave.exe --eval \"cd " 
                    + actingFolder + "; dynare code.mod; save -text saida.txt; exit\"");

        InputStream in = p.getInputStream();

        while(in.read != -1);

...
```

However, when I migrate it to the linux envior (Debian GNU/Linux 7, using a Glassfish 4.0 as the AppServer) and adjust the code to run in the said system it stopped working! Follows the code which I'm currently trying to run:

```
...

        p = rt.exec("/bin/bash -c /root/octave --eval \"cd " 
                                    + actingFolder + "; dynare code.mod; save -text saida.txt; exit\" --silent");

        InputStream in = p.getInputStream();

        while(in.read() != -1);

...
```

When this code runs it never ends: in.read() never returns -1 (InputStream code for the end of execution) so it never stops... Also, when octave is run it generates several exit files and none of them has been created, to what I assume that either the program wasn't able to be started or, for some reason, it was denied for the webApp to create the files as an output of the Octave application... I don't really know...

could you guys give me a hand?

and

P.S.:

I'm running this application through runtime because I know no better way in order to make Octave interpret the .mod. If there's another sollution I would really aprecciate it too.

---

### UPDATE

I tested througly and I can 100% guarantee that the application has the rights to create files in the server and Octave has full rights on my system... I should be able to run it correctly, right?

I also was able to verify that no: the program generates no errors on running the String on shell. In fact, even seems that it ignores the call on shell and goes on with the application, this imply 2 things: InputStream is returning -1 (ending correctly) and for some reason Octave isn't starting...

Any thoughs on why could this be?

And yes, Octave and all it's dependencys are installed correctly and I, myself, can manually call it from shell.

---

### UPDATE2

Now I'm getting what is happening!

Still trying to grasp everything at http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2 however I was able to understand some things by running the "TestExec" program in that guide.

First of all, at least in my situation, Runtime.Exec() WILL ALWAYS run the program at the beggning of the String. He them proceeds to try to feed the said program with the suplyied String, taking each space as if it was a line-break and feeding the program with it 'till an error or termination.

In my case he received "--eval", which is a Octave command, and as it was without any arguments it was ignored. Then it received "cd\"" and it caused and error, as it's not a Octave command without any address and caused the input to stop.

So this explains why it didn't caus any error in the execution (the error was handled by octave, thus not raising any Exception) and why nothing happened after the end of the proccess.

I'm working now on finding out how to input commands to Octave during execution.

Comment: Don't run a program as root if you don't need to!!

Comment: I really don't think that there's any other way to run this program other than running as root from shell =/